# Vector field notation - what is the law of multiplication?

Tags: manifolds

You are given three  smooth vector fields on a differentiable manifold $M$. Take the Lie bracket:

$[X,Y]f=X(Yf)-Y(Xf)$

My question is what is the law of multiplication between $X$ and $Y$? Composition of functions?

If the vector field can be written as $X=X^\mu\partial_\mu$, then the above expression becomes:

$[X,Y]f=X^\mu(\partial_\mu Y^\nu)\partial_\nu f +X^\mu Y^\mu \partial_\mu \partial_\nu f-Y^\nu(\partial_\nu X^\mu)\partial_\mu f - Y^\nu X^\mu \partial_\nu \partial_\mu f$

Why is it allowed to change the order of $Y^\nu$ and $X^\mu$ and of the derivatives?

Comment: I think you mean "vector fields," not "vector spaces."

Comment: Indeed, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that vector fields are given by derivations on the space of smooth functions. That is, they are maps
$$
D_X : C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)
$$
In that case, it is really just the composition
$$
C^\infty(M) \xrightarrow{X} C^\infty(M) \xrightarrow{Y} C^\infty(M)
$$
In coordinates, of course, this is just taking successive derivatives.